# Stuck jquery submit form in dialog

Tags: jquery, html, dialog

I want to submit the form which is done through dialog, the form is as below,

```
<div id="changeProfileDialogSND" style="display:none;width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 50px;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">

<form id="uploadImageAttrForm"  
        action="/local/..."     
        enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="padding-left: 10px">
        <h4>Upload your profile image:</h4><br/>
        <br/>           
        <input id="imageUploadAttr"
        size="40" name="image" type="file" />
        <br/> 
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="add" />

        <br/><br/>      
    </form>    </div>
<div id="changeProfileImage" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">ChangeImage</div>
```

I have following function to show this form in dialog,

```
$( "#changeProfileImage" ).click(function() {
    $( "#changeProfileDialogSND" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
});

$( "#changeProfileDialogSND" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 240,
    width: 440,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true
});
```

now the problem is this form is displaying in dialog and getting submitted through action,this form is basically uploading an image to my server,but i am not able to display the result back in same or different dialog,it goes to that url(action) and submits the file and shows plain white background and a message "file upload success",
i want it on stay on same dialog or same page and show another dialog with this msg,
any early help plz...

Answer (score 0):

If you are on modern browser which support postMessage (IE8+), after the user uploaded the file, server can return a page with JavaScript code that use postMessage to communicate with its parent and close the dialog.

If you want to host the upload control on the same page, <iframe> could help.

You can find postMessage demo at http://html5demos.com/postmessage.

Comment: im newbie to jquery, not getting-- in this example where it is submitting post request (and that to with a file to upload scenario)